# Inserting values into database with php, ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm struggling very hard to get this to work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have a register page that I want to take the data inserted into the form and INSERT it to the database with jQuery and AJAX. I'm not very experienced with AJAX AND jQuery so be gentle! :P I will show you the files that I have...

**sign_up.php**

```
    <?php
    include 'connect.php';
    include 'header.php';

    echo '<h2>Register</h2>';

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '
        <div class="container">  
        <form id="submit" method="post" action="">  
        <fieldset>  
        <legend> Enter Information </legend>  
        <br/>
        <label for="user_name">Your username: </label>
        <br/>
        <input id="user_name" class="text" name="user_name" size="20" type="text">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="user_pass">Your password: </label>
        <br/>
        <input id="user_pass" class="text" name="user_pass" size="20" type="password">  
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="user_pass_check">Confirm password: </label>
        <br/>
        <input id="user_pass_check" class="text" name="user_pass_check" size="20" type="password">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label for="user_email">Email: </label>
        <br/>
        <input id="user_email" class="text" name="user_email" size="20" type="email">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button class="button positive" type="submit"> <img src="like.png" alt=""> Register </button>  
        </fieldset>  
        </form>  
        <div class="success" style="display: none;"> You are now a registered user!</div>  
        </div>';
    }
    else {
        $errors = array();
        //Checks the errors
        if(isset($_POST['user_name']) == NULL)
        {
                //if the user name is larger than 30 characters
                $errors[] = 'Please enter your username.';
        }   

        //Checks the password
        if(isset($_POST['user_pass']) == NULL)
        {
                $errors[] = 'Please enter your password.';
        }
        else
        {
                if($_POST['user_pass'] != $_POST['user_pass_check'])
                {
                    $errors[] = 'The two passwords did not match.';
                }
        }

        if(!empty($errors)) //Checks for empty fields
        {
                echo 'Please check that all the fields are filled in.<br /><br />';
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach($errors as $key => $value) //walk through the array so all the errors get displayed
                {
                        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; //this generates a list with errors
                }
                echo '</ul>';
        }
 }
?>
```

in my header.php (which I include in every page) I included **addMembers.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("form#submit").submit(function() {

        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below  
        var user_name = $('#user_name').val();  
        var user_email = $('#user_email').val();
        var user_pass= $('#user_pass').val();

        //$user_name = $('#user_name').val();
        //$user_email = $('#user_email').val();
        //$password = $('#password').val();

        alert(user_name);

            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "ajax.php",  
                data: "user_name="+ user_name +"&user_email="+ user_email +"$user_pass=" + user_pass,  
                success: function(){  
                    $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});  
                }  
            });

            //alert("ji");

        return false;  
        });  
});
```

and then my ajax.php that gets the data and must insert it into the database but it doesn't! :(

```
<?php
        include 'connect.php';
        include 'header.php';

        // CLIENT INFORMATION  
        $user_name  = $_POST['user_name'];  
        $user_email   = $_POST['user_email'];  
        $user_pass   = $_POST['user_pass'];  

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO
                      users(`user_name`, `user_pass`, `user_email` , `user_date` , `user_level`)
                VALUES('$user_name', '$user_pass', '$user_email', NOW() , 0)" OR trigger_error(mysql_error())); 
?>
```

PLEASE help...

Thanks a lot!

Joe

Comment: What's not working? Also, use `$('#user_name').val();` to get a field value. And where's your insert?

Comment: data: "user_name="+ user_name +"&user_email="+ user_email +"& password=" + password,   & sign missing before user_email

Comment: sidenote: this `if(!ctype_alnum($_POST['user_name'])){$errors[] = 'That user name is allready taken.';}` is misleading, you surely didn't mean that

Comment: I have updated the post/question. Please have a look again! Sorry for the first upload... Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bit of things not right here:

**html:**

Give a type="submit" to your button:

```
<button type="submit" class="...>...</button>
```

**jQuery**:

Don't use attr() to get a form value, but use val(). Also, note how you built your query string. You might also want to use serialize(), which shortens your code a bit:

```
$("form#submit").submit(function() {

    var dataString = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "ajax.php",  
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){  
                $(this).hide();
                $('div.success').fadeIn();  
            }  
        });  
    return false;  
    });
```

**PHP**:

You **didn't show your ajax.php**, what is it doing? 
Why do you make a check in sign_up.php, if you're calling ajax?

Also, this piece of code:

```
if(!ctype_alnum($_POST['user_name']))
{
  $errors[] = 'That user name is allready taken.';
}
```

is misleading, ctype_alnum() does check if username has only alphabetical characters or numbers, what's this thing about a username being already taken?

**Mysql:**

<strike>you dint' provide your INSERT query, so noone can tell if that's failing too or not</strike>

**UPDATE:**

Your query has more columns than values.
Also, what is htmlspecialchars() good to here? to avoid SQL injections you need to use [**mysql_real_escape_string()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Escaping html before entering the database is useless

Make sure you have an open connection when calling mysql_real_escape_string().

Should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users 
             (`user_name`,`user_pass`,`user_email`,`user_date`,`user_level`)
             VALUES ('$user_name','$password','$user_email','missingvalue','missingvalue')"
            ) OR trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Comment: wow ok! thanks for the help! I've uploaded the ajax.php so that you can see what I'm doing. So far I've edited the files as far as I can! Please have a look again...

Comment: so what must I then do with the $user_name  = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['user_name'])); ?

Comment: @Joemeister updated my answer. Nothing, if you want to use that function use it on output, not before entering the database

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax.php",  
    data: "user_name="+ user_name + "&user_email=" + user_email + "&password=" + password,
    success: function(){  
        $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});  
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

show the ajax.php, besides earlyer comments like : ' $('#user_name').val();','ampersant before user_email'... seems ok...